# Place the image next to the text in big screens and stack them one below the other for smaller screens

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, responsive-design, vs-web-site-project

I am trying to build my own portfolio website and I want it to be responsive. For the 'about me' section, I have placed my image on the left and a small introduction about myself on the right of the division. Now, when I reduce the screen size, I want my text to be placed below my image. Any idea how this can be done? Any help is appreciated.

Sorry for not posting the code earlier.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles1.css">
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="container2" id="container2">
    <div class="intro">
      <div class="column-img">
        <!-- My image goes here  -->
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="column-txt">
        <h2>Hello.</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
          book.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>




.container2 {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  background-color: #A8D0e6;
}


.intro{
  background: #f76c6c;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  height: 450px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.intro .column-img img{
  float: left;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 320px;
  height: 456px;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Please share a reduced version of your code that allows us to re-produce your issue and help you.

Comment: There are multiple methods to do it, you can use css grid or media query

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to do it would be to make the container/parent of your image and text to be set to flex, like so:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

and then, for each of your items:

```
.myimage {
   order: 1;
}

.mytext {
   order: 2;
}
```

But, still recommend you show us a code snippet of your work.